# How to disable cash on delivery if coupon code is applied

Tags: opencart, coupon

Using OpenCart 1.5.6 I want to hide *Cash on Delivery* payment option only in case when the customer uses any coupon code during the checkout. All other payment options should be available.

Is it possible to do so by coding?

I am trying to make changes in the script but can't find a correct way to do so.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to achieve by *coding*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes We can do with some code modification in

```
catalog->controller->checkout->payment_method
```

There Check weather the coupon was applied with the session

```
$this->session->data['coupon']
```

if the session was set, you want to remove the cod key array in the

```
$method_data (array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do that You will need to go file:

`catalog->model->payment->cod.php`

Search

`<$method_data = array();`

just add given below code after that

`if (isset($this->session->data['coupon']))

{   $status = false; }
`